# Dotplot with boxplot group summaries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting data by two categories, first the underlying data:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

d1 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(30),
                  x = rep(letters[1:6],  
                          c(6, 3, 8, 3, 4, 6)),
              group = rep(paste("g", 1:3, sep = ""),
                          c(9, 11, 10)))
```

Then I order factors

```
of <- ddply(d1, .(x), function(i) mean(i$v1))
of <- of[order(-of$V1),]
d1$x <- factor(d1$x, levels = of$x)
```

And this provides the following plot

```
ggplot(d1) + geom_point(aes( x = v1, y = x)) + 
             facet_grid(group ~ .,
                        scales = "free_y",
                        space = "free_y")
```

[image: First plot without total summaries]

But thne I also want to add a separate horizontal boxplot for each group, depicting the relevant distribution. I know the first step is to provide a "Total" space in the y axis:

```
d2 <- rbind(d1, 
        data.frame(v1 = NA,
                    x = "Total",
                group = unique(d1$group)))

 ggplot(d2) + geom_point(aes( x = v1, y = x)) + 
              facet_grid(group ~ .,
                         scales = "free_y",
                         space = "free_y")
```

Which provides the following, and here I'm stuck

[image: plot with total spot on y axis.]

I just want a horizontal boxplot next to the "Total" axis break, summarizing each group's data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting point would be to make two data frame - `d1` as your original data frame and `d2` where x values all are `Total`.

```
d2 <- d1
d2$x <- "Total"
```

Then use `d1` to make points and `d2` to make boxplots. Here is example with vertical alignment of boxplots where `x` values are used as x. Problem is that to have horizontal boxplot you have to use `coord_flip()`. Flipped axis and free scales can't be used together.

```
ggplot()+geom_point(data=d1,aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  geom_boxplot(data=d2,aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  facet_wrap(~group ,
             scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Workaround to get in direction you need would be to make three separate plots (one for each group) and then put them together with `grid.arrange()` for library `gridExtra`. For the first and second plot I removed all ticks, texts and titles for x axis.

```
library(gridExtra)

p1<-ggplot()+geom_point(data=subset(d1,group=="g1"),aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  geom_boxplot(data=subset(d2,group=="g1"),aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_grid(group~.)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2,2.5))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

p2<-ggplot()+geom_point(data=subset(d1,group=="g2"),aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  geom_boxplot(data=subset(d2,group=="g2"),aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_grid(group~.)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2,2.5))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

p3<-ggplot()+geom_point(data=subset(d1,group=="g3"),aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  geom_boxplot(data=subset(d2,group=="g3"),aes(x=x,y=v1))+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_grid(group~.)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2,2.5))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)
```

[image]